# React update localstorage data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, storage, local

I'm trying to update data from the local host. I have 2 interfaces "loggedInUsers" and "user", one with a default value and the other with an individual value. In this case it is the colour. what am I doing wrong here? I would like to change the current "white" color to "blue".

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const usersIdColor = loggedInUsers.map((e) => user?.find((u) => u.id === e.id && u.color !== e.color));
    if (usersIdColor) {
      localStorage.setItem(
        'logged_in_users',
        JSON.stringify([...loggedInUsers, { id: user.id, username: user.username, tenantId: user.tenantId, color: 'blue' }])
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: can you post what the user array and loggedInUsers array is? As in example data?

Comment: Also, take your time..... You don't need to frantically keep updating your post. :)

Comment: the loggedInUsers i just add an img. and the user array is the same but with individual user data. The color is just an example to easy understand what i want to do

Comment: on reload it adds me another object into the loggedInUsers array as well. I dont want to add another one I just want to replace the color with a new value

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent adding new entries you should filter over the logged in users entry and use that value in replacement.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const WHITE = 'white';
    const RED = 'red';
    const loggedInUserFiltered = loggedInUsers.filter(({color, ...loggedInUser}) => color === WHITE ? {...loggedInUser, color: RED} : {...loggedInUser, color});

    if (usersIdColor) {
      localStorage.setItem(
        'logged_in_users',
        JSON.stringify(loggedInUsers)
      );
    }
}, []);
```

You should also add your logic to retrieve only the wanted user using find and so on, like you did, or you can even add conditions to the filter method, that way you could do it all in a single statement.

Something like:

```
const FIRST_USER = 1;
const loggedInUserFiltered = loggedInUsers.filter(({color, id, ...loggedInUser}) => color === WHITE && id === FIRST_USER  ? {...loggedInUser, color: RED, id} : {...loggedInUser, color, id});
```

BTW: it's **local storage**.

Comment: Thank you as well, this is also working for me.

Answer (score 1):

With this code you are always going to add a new user to the logged_in_users array with the color blue. If you want to update the logged_in_users you need to update the value in the array. Something like this (Not sure how exactly you are matching the user:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const userIndex = loggedInUsers.findIndex((e) => user?.find((u) => u.id === e.id && u.color !== e.color));
    if (userIndex) {

      loggedInUsers[userIndex]={ id: user.id, username: user.username, tenantId: user.tenantId, color: 'blue' };

      localStorage.setItem(
        'logged_in_users',
        JSON.stringify(loggedInUsers)
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Matching the user is correct both arrays got the same id prop. With this code another new user is not added but its still not working hm..

Comment: is user userIndex correct? if you print loggedInUsers before setting what do you see?

Comment: I changed to if (!userIndex) and then its replaced the array with a new user

Comment: Sorry my fault, its working. The user array was undefined thats why it doesnt worked :D